# jquery how to fire the same event every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, timed-events

I've built a simple carousel with left and right scroll. Now I want to scroll automatically every 5 seconds. Here's my code:

```
function carousel(){
        $j('#carousel_ul li:first').before($j('#carousel_ul li:last'));

        $j('#right_scroll img').click(function(){

            var item_width = $j('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;

            var left_indent = parseInt($j('#carousel_ul').css('left')) - item_width;

            $j('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},800, 'easeOutExpo',function(){

                $j('#carousel_ul li:last').after($j('#carousel_ul li:first'));

                $j('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-750px'});
            });
        });

        $j('#left_scroll img').click(function(){

            var item_width = $j('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;

            var left_indent = parseInt($j('#carousel_ul').css('left')) + item_width;

            $j('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},800, 'easeOutExpo',function(){

            $j('#carousel_ul li:first').before($j('#carousel_ul li:last'));

            $j('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-750px'});
            });

        });
}
```

How do I achieve that?
Thanks in advance :)

Mauro

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use setInterval. Look:

```
window.setInterval(event, 5000);
```

And function event would be

```
function event() {
 $j("#right_scroll img").click();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Tks @cris! setTimeout calls only one time. I changed to setInterval.

Tks @bears! Now I pass a function to setInterval.

Comment: setTimeout will do it only once. setInterval will call the function over and over and over... setInterval is better for this situation.

Comment: *PLEASE* don't pass strings to `setInterval` and `setTimeout`! Pass a function: `setInterval(event, 5000);` and `setInterval(function () {$j("#right_scroll img").click();}, 5000);`

Comment: Thanks Topera! was easier than I imagined! :)

Answer (score 12):

```
var i = setInterval(carousel, 5000)
```

And to stop it later:

```
clearInterval(i);
```

Comment: Cris, call `carousel` will only re-bind events. You must call scroll to right or left.