# run jquery animation every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery

How can a get a jquery animation to run say every 5 seconds?

so for something like this.

```
$('.zoom_big').animate({opacity: 1},2000,functions()}{
          $('.zoom_big').animate({opacity: 0},2000);
 });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549853/jquery-how-to-fire-the-same-event-every-5-seconds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301529/jquery-fade-with-loop-and-delay

Answer (score 4):

You can use [javascript's `setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval):

```
var t = setInterval(function(){ // run the following function

    $('.zoom_big').animate({opacity: 1},2000,functions()}{
          $('.zoom_big').animate({opacity: 0},2000);
    });

},5000); // every 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
```

To stop it you can use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval)

```
clearInterval(t);
```